# Facebook deleted conversation callback

Tags: python-3.x, facebook

I have a chatbot, but when a user clicks "delete conversation" I want to delete the conversation related to this user in my backend system(GDPR).

But I can't find any callbacks or endpoints I can call in order to validate if I want to keep or delete a conversation.

Is there anyone who had similar issues and been able to come up with a solution?